# Change of Ownership

Tags: apex

I have shared a record using Manual Sharing to "User X" with Read/Write permission. "User X" not able to change the owner. Is there any possible way that the User can change the Owner. Can someone tell me how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

Only owner  share the  records.
You  can refer   this link

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327372&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not mention what **object** you are referring to

I will give you a breakdown that there are 3 types of Transfer (Owner change) permissions you can give to User X:

1. Transfer Leads - Ability to Change a Lead owner.
2. Transfer Case - Ability to Change a Case owner.
3. Transfer Record - Ability to Change owner of most records.

1 & 2 are found in Profile/Permission Set > **App Permissions**

3 is found in Profile/Permission Set > **System Permissions**

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the Object. I was trying on a custom object. Will owner transfer differ from Custom Object to Standard Object.

Comment: Did you already try the assigning the permission of "Transfer Record" to User X?

Comment: Yes, I have a sharing rule to assign the record to User X. Just now I have found that Ownership transfer is only possible for Leads and Case objects. Is that correct?

Comment: If you want to transfer ownership other than Leads and Case just assign "Transfer Record" to User X